# Drupal theme preprocess function - primary links and suckerfish menus

Tags: php, drupal, function, themes, preprocessor

I have a preprocess function that works fine when the menu is single level list.  However I would like it to work w/ suckerfish menus.  I want to add a class to the top level menu item so that I can style it.  This is the code I used for the single level menu:

```
function cti_flex_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

// Make a shortcut for the primary links variables
$primary_links = $vars['primary_links'];

// Loop thru the menu, adding a new class for CSS selectors
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($primary_links as $link => $attributes){
        // Append the new class to existing classes for each menu item
        $class = $attributes['attributes']['class'] . " item-$i";

        // Add revised classes back to the primary links temp variable
        $primary_links[$link]['attributes']['class'] = $class;
        $link['title'] = '<span class="hide">' . check_plain($link['title']) . '</span>';
        $i++;
        } // end the foreach loop

// reset the variable to contain the new markup
$vars['primary_links'] = $primary_links;

}
```

I've been trying to use the `menu_tree()` function to no avail, for example:

```
function cti_flex_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {

// Make a shortcut for the primary links variables
$primary_links = $vars['primary_links'];

// Loop thru the menu, adding a new class for CSS selectors
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($primary_links as $link => $attributes){
        // Append the new class to existing classes for each menu item
        $class = $attributes['attributes']['class'] . " item-$i";

        // Add revised classes back to the primary links temp variable
        $primary_links[$link]['attributes']['class'] = $class;
        $link['title'] = '<span class="hide">' . check_plain($link['title']) . '</span>';
        $i++;
        } // end the foreach loop

// reset the variable to contain the new markup
$vars['primary_links_tree'] = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_primary_links_source', '$primary_links'));

}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave up on this and found a great module that does what I need; [Nice Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus). Full css control of menus, excellent module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Nice Menus enables drop-down/right/left expandable menus. It uses only CSS for most browsers, with minimal Javascript for IE6. (Version 2 uses the Superfish jQuery plugin for all browsers, with an option to disable JS, and falls back to CSS-only for browsers that can handle it.)
>
> Three styles/types of menus are currently possible: horizontal, menus drop down; vertical, menus fly to the left; vertical, menus fly to the right. There is a handbook page that provides a list of sites that use Nice menus.
>
> Nice Menus creates blocks that may be associated with any existing site menu which can be placed wherever normal blocks can be placed in a theme. For themers, it is also possible to theme a menu as a Nice Menu directly by using the provided theme functions so a block is not necessary. A specific theme function for the Primary Links menu is available. The theme functions also allow a developer to pass in a custom menu tree of their making (i.e. not using a Drupal menu.) There is more information on how to use theme functions in the documentation.
>
> The module comes with a simple, generic color scheme which can be fully overridden either by adding the override CSS to the theme's normal stylesheet or by creating a Nice Menus CSS file and telling Nice Menus to use that rather than its own default one through the global theme configuration. Several CSS override examples are provided in the included README.txt file and in the handbook.